How to patch a 3rd party lib in a unit test with FastAPI client
I have an app/main.py for FastAPI which does:
import qdrant_client as QdrantClient
... 

qdrant_client = QdrantClient(url=...)
qdrant_client.create_collection(...)
...

app = FastAPI()
...

@app.get("/my_endpoint")
def handle_my_endpoint(query: str):
  ...
  qdrant_client.query_points(...)

And I want to write a unit for /my_endpoint.
So I have in the unit test file:
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from app.main import app

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('app.main.QdrantClient', qdrant_client=MagicMock())
    def test_my_endpoint(self, qdrant_client): 
        qdrant_client.create_collection.return_value = None
        with TestClient(app) as client:
            resp = client.get("/my_endpoint", params={...})
            ...

But it doesn't work, it insists on actually using the real client which tries to really call a Qdrant server, which fails... What am I missing to set up that patch correctly?

Move the initialization of qdrant_client into lifespan and refactor your code to get qdrant_client as a dependency:
import qdrant_client as QdrantClient

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    qdrant_client = QdrantClient(url=...)
    qdrant_client.create_collection(...)

    yield {"qdrant_client": qdrant_client}


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


async def get_qdrant_client(request: Request):
  return request.state._state["qdrant_client"]

@app.get("/my_endpoint")
def handle_my_endpoint(query: str, qdrant_client: Annotated[QdrantClient, Depends(get_qdrant_client)]):
  ...
  qdrant_client.query_points(...)

Then, override using standard FastAPI mechanism:
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from app.main import app, get_qdrant_client


@pytest.fixture(name="qdrant_client")
def get_qdrant_client_fixture():
    return MagicMock()

@pytest.fixture(name="test_client")
def get_test_client_fixture(qdrant_client):
    async def get_qdrant_client_mock():
        return qdrant_client

    app.dependency_overrides[get_qdrant_client] = get_qdrant_client_mock

    with TestClient(app) as client:
        yield client

    app.dependency_overrides.clear()



class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_my_endpoint(self, test_client: TestClient, qdrant_client): 
        # qdrant_client.create_collection.return_value = None
        qdrant_client.query_points.return_value = None
        resp = client.get("/my_endpoint", params={...})



It doesn't quite work, and I think it's because in the main.py, it creates a global instance of qdrant_client then calls some operations on that client before we even get to the dependency override.

Do you mean it's still trying to use real Qdrant server?

Since weoverriden dpendency, that global qdrant_client is not used anymore during test calls of endpoints. Make sure you are not using that global var in any other sub-functions. If you need to use it pass that local instance which you got via depends

Yes, it's still trying to use the qdrant server, apparently - I get connection refused HTTP errors.

I got it!
You need to move create_collection call into lifspan. I will update my answer in a couple of minutes

I didn't have good luck with lifespan. I'm not managing to use it to create global objects to use in the rest of the app.

Let me try your solution.

The tricky part of creating global objects from lifespan is that you need to declare that variable as global (global qdrant_client inside lifespan). Otherwise it will create local variable with the same name.
But my suggestion is to use request.state to store that client

Thank you! I'm going to try that.
